# Bounds for function using integral bound

Tags: measure-theory

I've stumbled upon the following problem and I'm wondering if there is an elegant way to solve it.

Let $I=[a,b], (X,\mathfrak{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space and $f$ and integrable function with respect to the measure $\mu$

Prove that if
 $$\mu(A)>0 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\mu(A)} \int_A f\,d\mu \quad \in I  \quad(\text{for }A\in \mathfrak{A})$$

Then $f(x)\in I $ for $\mu$-almost all $x  \in X$

I solved the problem using the monotony of integrals for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and then handled the cases $-\infty$ and $\infty$ but I haven't used the fact that $(X,\mathfrak{A},\mu)$ is a finite measure space. Which means probably that there's a small mistake in the proof. That's why I'm curious to see if there are better approaches.

Comment: Does your proof also work if $\mu(A)=\infty$ for some $A$?

Comment: Oh it fails because I get a fraction in the form of $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ ! But given the finiteness of the space this shouldn't happen! Thank you.